# matInput loses focus after each keystroke

Tags: angular-material, angular-material16

Consider the following markup:

```
<!-- inputs lose focus after each keystroke -->
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let targetValue of someArray; index as i">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="someArray[i]" />
</mat-form-field>

<!-- works as expected -->
<mat-form-field  *ngFor="let i of [0,1]">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="someArray[i]" />
</mat-form-field>

<!-- works as expected -->    
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let targetValue of someOtherArray; index as i">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="someArray[i]" />
</mat-form-field>
```

with this .ts:

```
  someArray: number[] = [5,6];
  someOtherArray: number[] = [3,4]
```

Using Angular Material 16.2.12 (haven't tested other versions), this yields three pairs input controls all bound to the same 2 values. The data binding works correctly on all 6 inputs, but the 1st pair of inputs loses focus after each keystroke.

Can you explain the bug that's happening here?